# url rewrite for subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do rewrite only for a subdirectory, but I have a problem with RewriteCond.
All my files are in `/abc`.

Here is my htaccess (/abc/.htaccess) file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/static/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files/ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So I want to rewrite every url to index.php except the existing files in `/static` and `/files`. But this code is rewriting `/static/a.jpg` too, since the request was `/abc/static/a.jpg`. I tried setting `RewriteBase` to `/abc/`, but nothing changed.

Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your .htaccess like this in `/abc/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /abc/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(static|files)(/|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This will exclude the whole folder, but I want only the existing files to be excluded from rewrite - I want to handle 404 pages with PHP, but you gave me an idea, and my new code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/9ZL2Dt5k The only problem with this is that when I open /abc/static or any other folder that exists, it redirects me to /abc/static/?_url=static